# AngularJS cutting the last two digits of big integer

Tags: angularjs

I'm using $http to make network requests inside an angular app.
I'm retrieving a list of objects with the corresponding ids (some of them are really big numbers) from an API, but the ids don't match. The last two digits are changed to zeros.

An example is: 792102584287322157, which appears 792102584287322100.

This is a really awkward behavior, so i tested the API through a client and the API is fine, the problem is really angular.

Has anyone experienced the same issue? How can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: has nothing to do with angular but with javascript handling of large numbers. Easily researched

Comment: Thanks.You're right, Javascript only handles 53 bit integers.